# How to throw an IllegalArgumentException when an array is null or empty?

Tags: java, throws

```java
    /**
     * This constructor accepts an array of points as input. Copy the points into the array points[]. 
     * 
     * @param  pts  input array of points 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if pts == null or pts.length == 0.
     */
    protected AbstractSorter(Point[] pts) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        try{
            for(int i = 0; i < pts.length; i++)
            {
                points[i] = pts[i];
            }
        }
        catch()
        {

        }
    }
```

I know this should be really simple, but how would I throw this exception with those conditions?

Comment: If `pts` is null you should probably throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @kaya3 Yeah it appears I am very confused... I am new to java. So what would it look like then? Sorry

Comment: Generally this is done at the beginning of the method. Uses the throw statement.

Comment: @kaya3 I edited it above. Does this look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this,

```
protected AbstractSorter(Point[] pts) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    if(pts == null || pts.length == 0 ){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < pts.length; i++)
    {
        points[i] = pts[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would an IllegalArgumentException be thrown in the try block ?

Comment: The try-catch block is for the other exceptions apart from IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Where would an Exception be thrown in the try block ? Why would you catch it ?

Comment: Yes, you correct. Now I have looked at the code I can there is no possible way for an exception in the try block.

Answer (score 2):

```
protected AbstractSorter(Point[] pts) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
        if(pts == null || pts.length ==0 )
          throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        for(int i = 0; i < pts.length; i++)
        {
            points[i] = pts[i];
        }
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid Java code because the `catch` block doesn't declare a variable for the exception to be caught. But more importantly there shouldn't be a `try` or `catch` block at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
     * This constructor accepts an array of points as input. Copy the points into the array points[]. 
     * 
     * @param  pts  input array of points 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if pts == null or pts.length == 0.
     */
    protected AbstractSorter(Point[] pts) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if(pts == null || pts.length == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < pts.length; i++)
                points[i] = pts[i];
        }
    }
```

This is what I have come up with, with your advice.

Comment: Nice one, yes, this is a correct solution. One thing I'll suggest is always use braces `{` ... `}` even for the `if` and `for` blocks here where there is only one statement inside them; it makes your code more readable, and makes it easier to edit without introducing bugs.

Comment: "else" is unnecessary after throw. Also it is unusual to answer your own question if there is a similar answer by someone else, and duplicate answers have little value.